# Program not displaying in console

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using the latest version of Xcode, and I can't see anything in the console when I run my program. I've tried all sorts as methods such as reopening the console, and I really need help. Here's the program:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Quiz Game
//
//  Created by MS Student on 3/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

#include <iostream>


    {
        int sa;
        sa=1;
        string answer;
        while (sa==1);
        cout<<"Welcome to:\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"My Quiz Game!\n";
        cout<<"Be excited.\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter HELP to recieve instructions, or enter START to begin.\n";
        cout<<"Commands are case-sensitive, and you must press Enter after inputting you        choice.\n";
        cin>>answer;
        if (answer == "HELP") {
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"So, here's your help.\n";
            cout<<"Questions will be asked of you, and you, well, have to answer them.\n";
            cout<<"Should kind of be obvious.\n";
            cout<<"However, should you happen not to be me, or someone who has never used the C++ language before,\n";
            cout<<"you need to know a few things.\n";
            cout<<"Answers must be in all caps, and you must press Enter after typing your answer.\n";
            cout<<"If you don't know how to type, then, well, I don't know what to tell you.";
            return 0;
        }
        cin.get();
    };

}
```

Comment: The second `#include <iostream>` looks a bit suspicious to me.

Comment: I deleted it, but that did nothing to help me.

Answer (score 4):

`while (sa==1);` will run an infinite loop, since `sa` is initially `1`. There's an extra `;` there.

Comment: So, I should delete it?

Comment: @Sssgth depends on what you want to do. My guess is you want the loop, but you want it to run the code beneath it, so you should enclose that in brackets - `while (sa==1){cout<<"Welcome to:\n"; .... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct while syntax:

```
while(contition)
{
  //do something
}
```

in your code you have (in meta-code):

> as far as 1=1, do nothing

you can see the "do nothing" as you put a ';' after while intead of '{'.

It is called infinite loop, you will never go after the while condition as it is always verified.

Moreover, why did you add an #include in main?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I deleted it.

Comment: You have gone wrong @Fylax, actually the problem was not in the infinite loop, but it was in the semicolon(;) preceding the while loop. Be sure from next time to check answers given by other users whether they make a sense or not and then try to rectify them or post a new answer.

Comment: @Suyog I tried compiling it before posting and deleting the "while(true)" made me it working. So I replied.
If you are wondering why I did not looked to other reply that's simple:
1) I can't reply there as I do not have enough reputation
2) I posted maybe 2 minutes after them, I did not notice their reply

Comment: hmm....the same things I also faced when I was having less reputation.....stack exchange should do something for that. Anyway, welcome to stack exchange, have a great time here.